# php substring (substr) to detect words not character

Tags: php, string, substring, strlen

so i have this string where its too long to be put in my report. my report should use only 36 char. but my string value is more than that :

```
$value = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" //43 character
```

if only get the 36 char so you'll get : "**The quick brown fox jumps over the l**"
but i want to divide the sentence by words not by character, so i want to make 2 variable from that

```
$var1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the" //instead of The quick brown fox jumps over the l
$var2 = "lazy dog"
```

how do i do it???

Comment: str_word_count(); maybe

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) here. Try this:

```
echo substr($value, 0, strpos(wordwrap($value, 36), "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function limit_text($text, $limit) {
      if (str_word_count($text, 0) > $limit) {
          $words = str_word_count($text, 2);
          $pos = array_keys($words);
          $text = substr($text, 0, $pos[$limit]) . '...';
      }
      return $text;
    }

echo limit_text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work on any given string, addding word by word and checking every time for limits.

```
 $var1=""; $var2="";
 $value="your string";
 while ($var1.strlen<36) {
    $n=strpos($value, " "); //length of first word
    if (($var1.strlen +$n)<36) {
       $var1=$var1+substr($value, 0, $n);//from beginning of value till the first 'space' char
       $value = substr($value, $n); //removing first word
     }
 }
 $var2=$value;//the remmaining is what is left for second row
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. Result will be array containing string chunk

```
$value = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$arr = explode(" ",$value);
$str_arr = array();
$str = $arr[0];
$char_limit = 36;
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
    $tmp_str = isset($arr[$key + 1])?$arr[$key + 1]:"";
    if(strlen($str." ".$tmp_str) <= $char_limit)
    {
        $str.=" ".$tmp_str;
    }
    else
    {
        $str_arr[]=$str;
        $str=$tmp_str;
    }

}
$str_arr[]=$str;
print_r ($str_arr);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/Zg7fo)